# generate items from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, generator

I'm using python 3.3

I have a dictionary

dict = {'a': (3,1), 'b': (1,2), 'c': (1,1)}

i'm trying to generate one item at a time
when I write item I mean 
item1 = 'a': (3,1)
item2 = 'b': (1,2)
etc'

i have tried:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    temp = [key, value]
    yield temp
```

or

```
for item in dict:
    yield dict[item],item
```

but both don't generate what I want.

any help will be greatly appreciated 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def my_generator(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        yield {key: value}

d =  {'a': (3,1), 'b': (1,2), 'c': (1,1)}
for subdict in my_generator(d):
    print subdict
```

This would yield:

```
{'a': (3,1)}
{'b': (1,2)}
{'c': (1,1)}
```